# Snowflake:Timediff between two timestamps

Tags: timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

We have a teradata logic to minus on two timestamps columns and consider HOUR(4) TO SECOND

[image]

We have to convert the same in Snowflake to commence the same logic. Have tried the below set, but unable to have the data correctly populated for a smaller to bigger timestamp difference.

Looking for a suitable change to have the equivalent snowflake result:

[image]

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(NANOSECOND,'2019-10-21 18:30:00.000','2019-09-10 00:40:00.950000') AS TIME_SEC, SIGN(TIME_SEC) AS SIGN1 ,
TO_CHAR(TIME_FROM_PARTS(0,0,0,TIME_SEC),'MI:SS.FF3') AS TIMESTAMP, round(TIME_SEC/3600000000000)::STRING as day1, CONCAT(DECODE(DAY1,'0',SIGN1||'0',DAY1),':',TIMESTAMP) ;
```

We are seeing for a equivalent version for

```
select (TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 00:40:00.000000') - TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 18:30:00.00000')) HOUR(4) to SECOND;
select (TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 00:40:00.000000') - TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 18:30:00.00000')) DAY(3) to SECOND;
```

Example and reference after retry:

[image]

```
--Positive diff
select datediff(day, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850')  ) - '1' d, datediff(second, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') ) c , iff(c<0,'-','')||d||' '||to_time(abs(c)::varchar) out;
SF output : 0 22:11:38
select ( TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') - TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') ) day(4) to second;
TD output : 0 22:11:38.200000

--Negative diff
select datediff(day, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') , TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') ) + '1' d, datediff(second, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') , TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') ) c , iff(c<0,'-','')||d||' '||to_time(abs(c)::varchar) out;
SF output: -0 22:11:38
select ( TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') - TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850')  ) day(4) to second;;
TD output: -0 22:11:38.200000
```

In the same way we have to do for HOUR(4) to SECOND

Comment: Hi - please can you update your question to explain what the Teradata syntax “HOUR(4) TO SECOND” actually does? It would be easier to understand if you just provided some sample data, the result you were trying to achieve and explained the logic necessary to achieve the result

Comment: The Teradata syntax will return a string of "hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS".  WIth the dates above:  `select (timestamp '2019-10-21 18:30:00.000' - timestamp '2019-09-10 00:40:00.950000') hour(4) to second` will return `1001:49:59.050000`

Answer (score 0):

Use below code -

```
select datediff(second, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 18:30:00.00000') , TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-21 00:40:00.000000') ) c , iff(c<0,'-','')||   to_time(abs(c)::varchar) out
```

[image]

First, we calculate time differences in second.
Then, convert it to hh24:mi:ss.
Then, check if its +ve or -ve and add sign accordingly using iif.

EDIT :
Looks like you are looking for milliseconds as well. This will give you that   `select datediff(milliseconds, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') , TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') ) c , iff(c<0,'-','')||d||' '|| to_char(to_timestamp(abs(c)::varchar), 'hh24:mi:ss.SSSS') out;`

Here we are checking differences in milliscoend and then converting it to timestamp.

Comment: May be good enough if all you are doing is displaying the value AND the difference never exceeds 24 hours. Teradata returns an INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND datatype (up to 4 digits for the hours, 2 digits for minutes, 2 digits before and 6 digits after the decimal point for seconds). It's the client you are using that converts it to a string for display purposes. If you are using the INTERVAL type in later calculations, you'll probably need to convert the logic to use a single unit at the most granular level needed, e.g. second or microsecond.

Comment: @Koushik Roy, Thank you, this is fine from hh:mm:ss time till seconds, but it is not working when adding milliseconds as well, the output completely changing.
1. For DAY(3) to SECONDS -> it should give minus between two timestamps ->  DDD  HH:MM:SS.mmm
2. For HOUR(4) to SECONDS -> it should give minus between two timestamps ->  HHHH:MM:SS.mmm

Comment: can you pls give some example where its not working?

Comment: @Koushik Roy - FYI, Updated an example in the main question.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for milliseconds as well. This will give you that `  select datediff(milliseconds, TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-10 16:44:59.850') , TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-09-09 18:33:21.650') ) c , iff(c<0,'-','')||d||' '|| to_char(to_timestamp(abs(c)::varchar), 'hh24:mi:ss.SSSS') out;`

Comment: @Koushik Roy, The milliseconds, “SSSS” resembles or considering he seconds. So seconds value is printing twice as milliseconds. For exp: “16:44:59.5959”

Comment: Milliseconds format element would be FF6